# Chessboard Game Excercise c#

Tags: c#, algorithm

### Problem 2 – Chessboard Game

Goshko is a keen chess player. One day he was bored with his work and decided to take a break and create a game using the chessboard. He takes a string, e.g. "Software University_2345", converts its symbols to numbers through their ASCII codes and fills a chessboard with them. He takes the values of capital and small letters and digits only. The value of any other symbol is zero. He fills the board’s squares with the numbers, from left to right and from top to bottom (see the example below). The size of the chessboard is n*n (e.g. n = 5) and it always starts with a black square. N will always be an odd number.

```
S   o   f   t   w       

a   r   e       U       

n   i   v   e   r       

s   i   t   y   _       

2   3   4   5       



83  111 102 116 119

97  114 101 0   85

110 105 118 101 114

115 105 116 121 0

50  51  52  53  0
```

Let’s assume that there are two competing teams: the black team and the white team. Every team’s score is the sum of the values in its squares. However if a square contains a capital letter its value should be given to the opposing team. In the example above the scores are calculated as follows:

**White Team Score** = 83 'S' + 111 'o' + 116 't' + 97 'a' + 101 'e' + 105 'i' + 101 'e' + 115 's' + 116 't' + 51 '3' + 53 '5' = 1049

**Black Team Score** = 102 'f' + 119 'w' + 114 'r' + 85 'U' + 110 'n' + 118 'v' + 114 'r' + 105 'i' + 121 'y' + 50 '2' + 52 '4' = 1090.

**Input**
The input data should be read from the console.

•   The first line holds the size n of the chessboard.

•   The second line holds the input string.

The input data will always be valid and in the format described. There is no need to check it explicitly.

**Output**
The output should be printed on the console.

•   The first output line holds the winning team in format: “The winner is: {name} team”.

•   The second line holds the difference between the scores of the winning and the losing team.

•   In case the score is equal, print “Equal result: {points}”. Do not print the difference in this case!

Here is my current code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ChessboardGame
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int boardSize = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            string inputString = Console.ReadLine();
            char[,] board = new char[boardSize, boardSize];
            int p = inputString.Length;                                         //check so it doesnt go out of range of the string
            int i = 0;                                                          //to know which element of the string to store into the matrix
            int whiteScore = 0;
            int blackScore = 0;
            int oddOrEven = 0;                                                  //to know if the cell is odd or even

            for (int row = 0; row < boardSize; row++)                           //filling the matrix
            {
                if (p == 0)
                    break;

                for (int col = 0; col < boardSize; col++)
                {
                    if (p == 0)
                        break;

                    board[row, col] = inputString[i];
                    i++;
                    p--;
                }
            }                                                                  
            for (int row = 0; row < boardSize; row++)                           //calculating score
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < boardSize; col++)
                {
                    if (oddOrEven % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        if (!(((int)board[row, col] >= 65 && (int)board[row, col] <= 90) && ((int)board[row, col] >= 97 && (int)board[row, col] <= 122)))
                        {
                            if ((int)board[row, col] >= 65 && (int)board[row, col] <= 90)
                            {
                                whiteScore += (int)board[row, col];
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                blackScore += (int)board[row, col];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (!(((int)board[row, col] >= 65 && (int)board[row, col] <= 90) && ((int)board[row, col] >= 97 && (int)board[row, col] <= 122)))
                        {
                            if ((int)board[row, col] >= 65 && (int)board[row, col] <= 90)
                            {
                                blackScore += (int)board[row, col];
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                whiteScore += (int)board[row, col];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    oddOrEven++;
                }
            }
            if (whiteScore > blackScore)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The winner is: white team");
                Console.WriteLine(whiteScore - blackScore);
            }
            else if (blackScore > whiteScore)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The winner is: black team");
                Console.WriteLine(blackScore - whiteScore);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Equal result: {0}", whiteScore);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I am getting wrong answers.

I enter

> 5
>   Software University_2345

I expect

> The winner is: black team
>   41

But I receive

> The winner is: white team
>   22

I just can't figure it out. I've been trying to switch the teams places. Also I think there might be something wrong with my expression for checking weather a letter is capital or not.

Comment: This sounds like a *great* opportunity to familiarize yourself with the use of a debugger. *Guessing* what you think the problem might be is a start, but actually *stepping through the code* as it executes and *examining* the behavior will allow you to validate your logic. The code isn't a black box, you can examine it and debug it.

Comment: You should try your code with smaller boards, and simpler words, to start with.

Comment: I used the debugger and as I said I think there might be something wrong with my expression to check if the letter is capital(using ASCII code) I decided to put the whole code here in case that wasn't the problem

Comment: Add  Console.WriteLine("W "+whiteScore); where the white score is added together, and the same but "B" where your blackscore is calculated. Should help you see what's wrong. Also buy Go6ko a Boza s Bani4ka ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a few changes in your loops:

```
for (int row = 0; row < boardSize; row++) //calculating score
{
    for (int col = 0; col < boardSize; col++)
    {
        char c = board[row, col];
        if (oddOrEven % 2 == 0)
        {
            if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
            {
                if (char.IsUpper(c))
                {
                    whiteScore += c;
                }
                else
                {
                    blackScore += c;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(c);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
            {
                if (char.IsUpper(c))
                {
                    blackScore += c;
                }
                else
                {
                    whiteScore += c;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(c);
            }
        }
        oddOrEven++;
    }
}
```

It now works like a charm. The issue was the way you were checking is a char was valid or not. `.Net` framework is full of useful tools, don't hesitate to use them. Here I just used `char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)` to save you.